# erase invalidates iterator in Coverity

Tags: c++, iterator, static-analysis, coverity

We're currently using Coverity's Synapsis which runs over the code base and flags lines of code that would cause a bug and such.

I have this code:

```
auto it = std::find_if(my_container.my_list.begin(), my_container.my_list.end(),
            [&](my_struct temp)
            {
                return temp._id == id;
            });

/*To erase duplicates*/
if (it != my_container.my_list.end())
{
     my_container.my_list.erase(it);
}
```

The `erase` part is being recognized as "erase invalidates iterator " then "Using invalid iterator (INVALIDATE_ITERATOR)". I'm not sure I understand why this is so. The iterator is not used after this code so it should be safe, right?

Comment: Why are you comparing `it` with the `end()` iterator from what appears to be a completely unrelated sequence? The iterator `it` is valid only within the space of `my_container.my_list`, not `m_ue_params.ues`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good catch! I updated my code above, I just forgot to replace the variable names for my example so it would be more understandable what it represents

Comment: it = my_container.my_list.erase(it); to update the iterator after the erase.

Comment: @dgsomerton Oh, I think I get it now, thanks. So it appears that `it` may still be used after it's erased?

Comment: @phoenixWright Impossible for us to say. The code after this was not included, and you stated in your question that "The iterator is not used after this code...". As written, if `it` is never used after this, and the code shown *exactly* as it is here now, with your changes making my first comment irrelevant, should work. if it doesn't, something else is wrong that we can't see. Unrelated, `my_struct temp` should probably be a const reference unless you like making needless copies of things.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, `it` is not used anymore after the code above. I was pertaining to how Coverity sees it as, maybe it assumes that `it` _may_ still be used after that :) And thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It's too bad that you could not simply post the entire function instead of just that short section.  Then someone could have given a more definitive answer.  As it stands now it is an open question that will not likely be useful for anyone else in the future.